# React js: how to convert string record count to integer in Export All to Excel

Tags: excel, reactjs

I am using export all to Excel functionality to export the React table data into an Excel sheet. All the data is getting inserted as string format, but I wanted record count to be stored as integer format, however it is being stored as string format.

Export all to Excel code:

```
<div id="excelLayer">
    <Workbook filename='DownloadedReport.xlsx' element={<a href="javascript:void(null)" className='excel_div'>Export all to Excel</a>}>
    <Workbook.Sheet data={this.state.data} name="Table Data">
    <Workbook.Column label="From" value="senderID"/>
    <Workbook.Column label="To" value="receiverID"/>
    <Workbook.Column label="Transaction File" value="fileName"/>
    <Workbook.Column label="Transaction Date" value="transationDate"/>
    <Workbook.Column label="Record Count" value="recordCount"/>
    <Workbook.Column label="Status" value="status"/>
    </Workbook.Sheet>
    </Workbook>
</div>
```

React table Record Count column code: This code is used for record count column sorting.

```
{Header: 'Record Count',accessor: 'recordCount', style: {textAlign: "center"},
  sortMethod: (a, b) => {
    if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
      return a > b ? 1 : -1;
      }
      return a - b;
    }
  },
```

Exported Excel data:

[image]

How to handle this in code so that the data will automatically be stored as integer?

Comment: Which library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

***Can you make sure you are giving recordCount value as string?***

I tried using **react-excel-workbook** with integer values and the downloaded excel is proper. 
And if I use string, the excel has string formatted values.

NOTE: Assuming your "recordCount" is always int I have used parseInt. If it can be float please modify  `<Workbook.Column label="recordTotal" value={row => parseInt(row.recordTotal)}  />` accordingly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Workbook from 'react-excel-workbook'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const data1 = [
      {
        recordTotal: '123',
        status: 'Not started',
      },
      {
        recordTotal: '12',
        status: 'in progress',
      },
      {
        recordTotal: '111',
        status: 'Completed',
      }
    ]

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Workbook filename="example.xlsx" element={<a href="javascript:void(null)" className='excel_div'>Export all to Excel</a>}>
          <Workbook.Sheet data={data1} name="Sheet A">
            <Workbook.Column label="recordTotal" value={row => parseInt(row.recordTotal)}  />
            <Workbook.Column label="status" value="status" />
          </Workbook.Sheet>
        </Workbook>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Below is the downloaded excel.

[image]

Comment: Yes i am storing as a string.

Comment: So is it possible to change it to a number?

Comment: No It is not possible to convert it to Integer. i can only do manupulation either in column or in workbook.  <Workbook.Column label="Record Count" value="recordCount"/>  Is there any thing that we can add here to convert it to inetger???

Comment: Edited the answer. have a look